# É possivel alterar permanentemente um arquivo html com Javascript?

Tags: javascript

Alterar dinamicamente eu sei que é possível, mas gostaria de saber se é possível alterar um arquivo html permanentemente com JavaScript

Answer (score 2, accepted):

É possível, se você estiver rodando JavaScript no seu back end via NodeJS.

Porém pela pergunta da-se a entender que você está se questionando se é possível rodar um código em JavaScript na máquina do usuário para alterar o código fonte que está no seu servidor, e se esse é o caso, a resposta é não. O usuário pode no máximo fazer uma requisição para o servidor para que então o servidor se encarregue de modificar permanentemente um arquivo que está hospedado no mesmo.